# C++ Instantiation

Tags: c++

I have `Vector` class, representing a 3D point, written as follows in `Vector.h`:

```
class Vector {
  public:
    float x,y,z;
    Vector(float _x=0.0,float _y=0.0,float _z=0.0){x=_x;y=_y;z=_z;};
    operator float *() { return &x;};
};
```

I also declare a `extern vector<Vector>model_vertices;` on `model.h`

On a `model.cpp` file I implement `Vector.h` and declare a `std::vector<Vector>model_vertices; globally` (yes, I know the vector/Vector thing is confusing, but I must use the Vector naming for consistency).

On `model.cpp`, when initializing the contents of this vector I use a for loop with the following content:

```
float X,Y,Z;

offFileStream>>X;
offFileStream>>Y;
offFileStream>>Z;


Vector v=new Vector(X,Y,Z);


model_vertices[loadVertexIndex]=v;
```

I get the following error:

```
error C2440: 'initializing' : cannot convert from 'Vector *' to 'Vector'
```

Why?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The error is on this line:

```
Vector v=new Vector(X,Y,Z);
```

`v` is of type `Vector`, but `new Vector(X,Y,Z)` returns a `Vector*`:

What you probably wanted instead is just:

```
Vector v(X,Y,Z);
```

As a side note, I didn't see you initialize a size for the `model_vertices`. So you may want to use `push_back()` instead.

Answer (score 3):

It's not quite clear what you're trying to achieve, but perhaps you're overthinking this.

First off, please forget the keyword `new`. Just pretend it doesn't exist. (By the time you'll need it, you'll know enough C++ to realize that you can ignore this post.)

Second, you can improve your class constructor to use an initializer list:

```
Vector(float _x = 0.0, float _y = 0.0, float _z = 0.0)
: x(_x), y(_y), z(_z)
{  }
```

Third, to populate a vector, just insert temporaries directly:

```
std::vector<Vector> v;
float x, y, z;

while (get_values(x,y,z))    // or any sort of loop you like
{
  v.push_back(Vector(x,y,z));
}
```

If you have a recent version of C++, you can use the more efficient emplacement instead:

```
 v.emplace_back(x, y, z);  // no temporary
```

Answer (score 2):

```
Vector v=new Vector(X,Y,Z);
model_vertices[loadVertexIndex]=v;
```

should be

```
Vector *v=new Vector(X,Y,Z);
model_vertices[loadVertexIndex]=*v;
```

`new()` allocated from the heap and it returns a pointer to an object.

If you want to call the constructor and allocate on the stack, do this instead.

```
Vector v(X,Y,Z);
```

Answer (score 1):

The new operator can only be used when asigning to a pointer. If you just want to have an object v of type vector then you should use:
`Vector v(X,Y,Z);`
If you would like to have a pointer to Vector object then you should use:
`Vector *v=new Vector(X,Y,Z);`